# python pandas: fulfill condition and assign a value to it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am really hoping you can help me here...I need to assign a label(df_label) to an exact file within dataframe (df_data) and save all labels that appear in each file in a separate txt file (that's an easy bit)

```
df_data:

              file_name  file_start   file_end
0   20190201_000004.wav       0.000   1196.000
1   20190201_002003.wav    1196.000   2392.992
2   20190201_004004.wav    2392.992   3588.992
3   20190201_010003.wav    3588.992   4785.984
4   20190201_012003.wav    4785.984   5982.976
```

```
df_label:
Begin Time (s)
0     27467.100000
1     43830.400000
2     43830.800000
3     46378.200000
```

I have tried to switch to np.array and use for loop and np.where but without any success...

Comment: You need to provide more info. What is the relation between `df_data` and `df_label`? how do you determine a label belongs to a file?

Comment: Appologies. I will try to explain it better. df_labels include labels created within the 24h period covered by all files in my df_data. So a label will fit within the time span of a one file listed. There may be many labels coresponding to one file and some files wont have labels at all. I believe i should set conditions like: label_time bigger than and smaller that to assign label to a file but i am not sure how to do it. Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

If the time values in `df_label` fall under exactly one entry in `df_data`, you can use the following

```py
def get_file_name(begin_time):
    file_names = df_data[
        (df_data["file_start"] <= begin_time)
         & (df_data["file_end"] >= begin_time)
    ]["file_name"].values
    return file_names.values[0] if file_names.values.size > 0 else None

df_label["file_name"] = df_label["Begin Time (s)"].apply(get_label)
```

This will add another col `file_name` to `df_label`

Comment: this makes sens but when applied i am getting this error `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 `

Comment: Could you help me with solving this error issue please?

Comment: Try the edit (your df_label probably has issues)

Comment: thank you it works briliantly! I had to remove `.values` as np.array has no atribitue values, once that was done code run smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

If the labels from `df_label` matches the order of files in `df_data` you can simply:

- add the labels as new column of `df_data` (`df_data["label"] = df_label["Begin Time (s)"]`).

or

- use DataFrame.merge() function (`df_data = df_data.merge(df_labels, left_index=True, right_index=True)`).

More about merging/joining with examples you can find here:

https://thispointer.com/pandas-how-to-merge-dataframes-by-index-using-dataframe-merge-part-3/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: thanks, tried that but it does not work. each label fits within timse start time end of a one file and should be assigin to it. So i bassically need to check if each label falls within start end time of each file and if so assign label to a file.